# Why can't I change individual char of a string pointer in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

Why does the following code gives me `Exception has occurred. Segmentation fault`

```
char* someString = "original string";
someString[1] = 'O';
```

Comment: This declaration creates a char pointer, pointing to a const string. It will work if you instead declare with for example `char someString[20] = "original string";`

Comment: String literals are read-only. See [C11 6.4.5p7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5): "If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: In C all literal strings (like `"original string"`) are really **non-modifiable** arrays of characters, including the null-terminator. Attempting to modify a literal string leads to *undefined behavior*. That's why you should make it a habit to always use `const char *` for pointers to literal strings.

Comment: user97662, Note: `someString[1] = 'O';` _might_ work.  Might not.  It is undefined.  Anything is allowed.  Code is not required to seg. fault.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny `"original string"` is not a [const string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70184192/why-cant-i-change-individual-char-of-a-string-pointer-in-c#comment124066652_70184192) - its type is not `const` anything.  Yet  changes to a _string literal_ should not be attempted is good advice. 
 Good to treat it as if is was a `const` _string_.